# How to loop array data to generate HTML select dropdown?

Tags: php, html, select, if-statement, foreach

I would like to create dynamic dropdown on products in my webstore, but i have some problem looping data. I want to loop data with PHP. My output is data array and it looks like that:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[34]
      public 'id_attribute_option' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'option_name' => string 'Black' (length=5)
      public 'name' => string 'Color' (length=5)
      public 'id_attribute' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'id_attribute_option' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'option_name' => string 'Green' (length=6)
      public 'name' => string 'Color' (length=5)
      public 'id_attribute' => string '2' (length=1) 
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'id_attribute_option' => string '84' (length=2)
      public 'option_name' => string 'S' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Size' (length=8)
      public 'id_attribute' => string '9' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'id_attribute_option' => string '85' (length=2)
      public 'option_name' => string 'M' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Size' (length=8)
      public 'id_attribute' => string '9' (length=1)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'id_attribute_option' => string '86' (length=2)
      public 'option_name' => string 'L' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Size' (length=8)
      public 'id_attribute' => string '9' (length=1)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[39]
      public 'id_attribute_option' => string '87' (length=2)
      public 'option_name' => string 'XL' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Size' (length=8)
      public 'id_attribute' => string '9' (length=1)
```

And desired effect should be like this.

```
Color:<select>
      <option value="8">Black</option>
      <option value="10">Green</option>
    </select>
Size:<select>
      <option value="84">S</option>
      <option value="85">M</option>
      <option value="86">L</option>
      <option value="87">XL</option>
    </select>
```

Can enybody help me?

Comment: Use a simple `foreach` loop. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I hava abused foreach loop and that didn't do it. :)
Now i need new angle so that's whay i have posted that question!

Comment: What is you solution with foreach loop?

Comment: What do you get when using `foreach` loop.

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik Please show us your attempt, so we can spot the error in your code.

Comment: Lol... Like i said. MY whole code was error and i need whole new angle on this. What i did before was not right in any way.

Comment: This is probably what i'm looking  for...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831941/select-dropdown-php-foreach-loop-with-optgroup-options?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you may separate them using this code ([DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c3438795845f9b9d2c4667d99953fa2d3584ace))

```
$colors = $sizes = array();
array_map(function($item) use(&$colors, &$sizes){
    if($item->name == 'Color') $colors[] = $item;
    if($item->name == 'Size') $sizes[] = $item;
}, $array);
```

Then use two different `foreach` loops, one for `colors` and one for `size` like

```
// BUild the Color select
echo "<select id='color'>";
foreach($colors as $color){
    echo "<option value='$color->id_attribute_option'>$color->option_name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

// Build the Size select
echo "<select id='size'>";
foreach($sizes as $size){
    echo "<option value='$size->id_attribute_option'>$size->option_name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Very good point! Tnx!
There is only one more problem...
I must asume, that sometimes products have no attributes, some times they have size and gender, some times only gender... If you know what i mean? This selects have to be dynamical, based on db data foreach product...

Comment: Then you should have another array for genders as well but you have to make be determined about the data.

Comment: and what if you have x or let say 100 selects in your DB? I don't want to be determined about the data :)

Comment: You need a way to find out which select you want to build and the data source, if that source contain certain types of data for select then build it.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($yourArray as $item)
{
  // you are dealing with objects so $item->option_name for example
  // this should be easy :p
  // there's no perfect way to do most things
  // so that bottom link you pasted in the comments isn't
  // going to teach you anything but how to copy others
}
```