# php how to show category and then subcategory in select dropdown?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where i am saving category and product name :

```
+-----------------------+
|       products        |
+-----------------------+
| id  name     cat_name |
| 1   lily     flower   |
| 2   hibiscus flower   |
| 3   cat      animal   |
| 4   dog      animal   |
+-----------------------+
```

I want to have a select list with first cat_name and inside that product 'name'

```
**flower**      
    -lily
    -hibiscus
**animal**  
    -cat
    -dog
```

how this can be achieved in select list. please help.

Comment: Use a `select` sql statement, then loop through the results to new categorized array(s) (throw some html in there for good measure), then implode the array(s). That's what I would do anyway...

Comment: ^ with that use `order by` and order it by the `cat_name` so all your animals, flowers, etc, are together.

Comment: @chris85 i tried that order by but i am not getting exactly next can u explain?

Comment: how can i iterate it in for loop?

Comment: i got an working answer here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831941/select-dropdown-php-foreach-loop-with-optgroup-options

Answer (score 0):

In html body it is the optgroup tag that groups options.

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="flower">
        <option value="whatever">lily</option>
        <option value="whatever">hibiscus</option>
    </optgroup>
    ...
</select>
```

Hope you get the idea.
 Note that these optgroups look pretty poor. Maybe you need some jquery plugin in additon to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get array like this

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1
        'name' => 'lily',
        'cat_name' =>'flower'

    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2
        'name' => 'hibiscus',
        'cat_name' =>'flower'

    ),
    .....
    );
```

then group data by cat

```
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($results  as $rs) {
      $key = $rs['cat_name'];
      if (!isset($groups[$key])){
        $groups[$key] = array();
      }
      $groups[$key][] = $rs;
    }
```

then loop $groups , echo html  option , like

```
//this not php code
 loop  groups {
        echo optgroup opentag
        loop groups[cat_name]{
            echo option tag
        }
        echo optgroup close tag
 }
```